# How to make neural network training less dependent on initial conditions?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

In this simple toy example, the network leans the XOR operation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score


    model = tf.keras.Sequential(layers=[
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
    ])

    model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, 
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)
    )

    x_train = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (10000, 2))
    tmp = x_train > 0
    y_train = (tmp[:, 0] ^ tmp[:, 1])

    model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=10)

    x_test = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (1000, 2))
    tmp = x_test > 0
    y_test = (tmp[:, 0] ^ tmp[:, 1])

    prediction = model.predict(x_test) > 0.5
    print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy_score(y_pred=prediction, y_true=y_test)}')
    print(f'recall: {recall_score(y_pred=prediction, y_true=y_test)}')
    print(f'precision: {precision_score(y_pred=prediction, y_true=y_test)}')
```

This example can also be found in the [tensorflow playground](https://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=relu&regularization=L1&batchSize=10&dataset=xor&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.01&regularizationRate=0.001&noise=0&networkShape=4&seed=0.22559&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false)

When the initial loss is <3, this will quickly converge (in 2-3 epochs). But sometimes the initial conditions lead it to have ~7 loss, in which case it never converges (not even after 1000 epochs).

It's easy to know right after the first epoch if it's going to work or not, but it makes searching for hyper parameters very difficult, since you never know if converged successfully by chance due to initial conditions, or if the hyper parameter is the cause.

Is there a way to make this network less dependent on initial conditions? A different optimizer? Some optimizer hyper parameter? weight regularization?

I've tried changing these, but didn't get consistent improvements.

In the playground example, it never gets stuck at this kind of high loss.

**Edit**: If you make the training long enough, it might jump to loss 7 even after settling on a good solution with loss < 0.03.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, there's no way to be 100% sure if it's the hyper params or the initial config.  You'll need to implement something for the case when there's divergence.

Practically though, you could:

1. Train multiple times, and incorporate how often the network converges into the strategy on selecting the best hyperparameters;.
2. Find some ranges for which you feel like the model is consistent.
3. Incorporate the initialization of your weights into your hyperparameter optimization. Right now they are randomly initiliazed, and are the cause of the problem. There's a number of ways to do this. Try playing around with different initilizers, but there's no "one best initiliazers for every ML problem".
4. Just fix the initial conditions. Fix the random seed that tensorflow uses for initilization using `tf.random.set_seed`, but that will affect your performance by a lot of course, so I don't think that's really what you want. You could make the claim that you are now sure that a network performs well because of the architecture, but that's only true for that specific random seed, not for all.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-initialize-a-neural-network-27564cfb5ffc), adding batchnorm should make the network less sensitive to the initialisation approach.